# What is the meaning of a construction like "no less X than Y"?

Tags: meaning

What exactly does "no less ... than ..." mean in this sentence?

> Aging can be accelerated no less by habits than by diseases.

I know that if the sentence read, "no more than," it would mean aging can't be accelerated by either habits or diseases, so I'm guessing the given sentence means aging can be  accelerated by both..? But the exact meaning doesn't register... Can someone clarify this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence assumes as true that

> Aging can be accelerated by diseases.

and is saying that

> Aging can also be accelerated by habits.

Which of these, habits or diseases, can accelerate aging the most?

> Aging can be accelerated by habits

no less than

> Aging can be accelerated by diseases.

So either Habits can accelerate aging more than diseases can; or habits and diseases can equally affect aging.

Put more simply

> In regard to accelerating aging, habits can be at least as bad as diseases can.